# How to manually close a port

Tags: linux, macos, networking, osx-lion, port

In OSX if I type netstat I can see certain things that have an established connection. I don't want to change any settings to close these, I just want to be able to close whatever I ports I choose in the terminal. How do you do that?

Comment: Do you want to close extant connections, prevent further ones on the same port, or both?

Answer (score 6):

You can't close an open socket just like this. Ideally, you would just kill the process that has established the connection.

Check your connections with `lsof` (`netstat` won't show the process), filtering the output with whatever connection status you want:

```
lsof -i
lsof -i | grep LISTEN
lsof -i | grep ESTABLISHED
```

Or, to get the port, e.g. `17500`:

```
lsof -i:17500
```

Then, just kill the process. For example:

```
$ lsof -i | grep "Skype"
Skype     438 werner    9u  IPv4 0xffffff801dd0c640      0t0  UDP localhost:52218
Skype     438 werner   42u  IPv4 0xffffff80231a7a08      0t0  TCP *:29429 (LISTEN)
Skype     438 werner   43u  IPv4 0xffffff8022e18a40      0t0  UDP *:29429
```

Kill Skype:

```
killall Skype
```

Note though that this won't prevent the connections from being made – something you have to specify in your Firewall preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Can also use the use the `fuser` or `netstat` commands.

`fuser` syntax is

```
fuser -k -n protocol portno
```

Example:

```
$ fuser -k -n udp 7777

7777/udp:            11774
```

The number 11774 is the pid.

`netstat` example:

```
$ sudo netstat -ap | grep :9050

tcp        0      0 localhost:9050          *:*       LISTEN      1613/tor
```

The number 1613 is the pid and "tor" is the process name.

Once you have the pid just end it using the kill or killall command

> kill pid

or

> killall -9 command_name

Comment: Your instructions are for showing the perceived symptoms described in the question, open ports belonging to processes. You left out how to accomplish the desired task, to close the port.

Comment: Still doesn't answer how to close a port. But rather kill the process that created/opened it. What if a process holds >1 open port. How could I kill one but not the other